# Issue loading missing assemblies in Xamarin.Forms project

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.ios

I'm building a Xamarin.Forms project and I had no problems starting up the project but all of a sudden when trying building the project I get the following Exception:

```
Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 
Could not load assembly 'Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract,
Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist
in the Mono for Android profile Filename: 'Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract.dll'
```

I have looked for where in my project the `Windows.Foundation` namespace is used but I can only find references to it in the `AppDelegate.cs` and `Main.cs` of the iOS-project.

Comment: could you please post more about what steps you did causes this exception?

Answer (score 1):

Apparantly the exception was a bit confusing because it was related to another assembly that was referenced. After I deleted that assembly, Windows.Foundation.FoundationUniversalContract, all worked fine.
When an how this reference was added is beyond me.