# Exception while loading Assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract'

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So XAML and C# are new to me but I have to write a cross platform app for my final year. I'm using Xamarin.Forms for this. All went well untill I got this error and have been stuck since.

Can't seem to build the app because of it. I can only test my app by using Xamarin Live player Live view and not all functionallities seem to work whenever I use the live function.

`` Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract.dll'
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver, ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver)   GrowersClassified.Android ``

I've checked my references and Mono.Android is there.
Is there any way I can fix this error? I don't know what causes it...

Thanks!

Comment: You might be having a similar issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47929082/issue-loading-missing-assemblies-in-xamarin-forms-project?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Hi @MikaalAnwar According to that post, the error has something to do with an assembly. Would that be an assembly in my CS or at the top of my XAML file?

Comment: Have you added any DLLs / References / Nuget Packages etc. recently? After which the project might've stopped working?

Comment: I've added the System.Net.Http and Plugin.Google Nuget packages, but everything worked fine after. I didn't mess with any DLL's and don't think I've added references